# Fetching data from eCommerce

Tags: php, web-crawler, e-commerce

I want to fetch product data from Flipkart and Amazon using their API.

```
<form action="test.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="searchdata">
    <label for="searchdata">Search Product</label>
    <input id="search" type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Not like this

```
$web_page_data =  file_get_contents("https://flipkart.com/search?q=".$search);
```

Please help me in implementing the same.

Comment: I'll gladly help. As soon as you explain exactly what problem you're facing and.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov It's not a problem but I don't have a vital solution. I want to create a search, a query will be stored and using the 'query' we'll display results from Amazon and Flipkart on a single page. I don't know how to proceed and I want to do this using their API.

Comment: You can't apply for an API key right now: 
https://affiliate.flipkart.com/disableRegistration  Retry on the 30th, I guess.  Maybe you should email them: https://affiliate.flipkart.com/contact-us

Comment: @nfnneil I have the API key and affiliate account, that's not an issue. But implementation is the one issue. Help me with that please